# Status of Java exotic identifiers

Tags: java, java-8, language-lawyer, java-7, jls

While looking at the [Java invokedynamic documentation](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/mlvm/InterfaceDynamic), I saw the following example of a Java feature called "exotic identifiers":

```
int #"strange variable name" = 42;
System.out.println(#"strange variable name");  // prints 42
```

I was unable to get this to work on an openjdk8 on my machine. Further googling found a few bug reports relating to this feature but not much else. Specifically [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6746458),and  [this other bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6868490).

Yet another bug [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6999438) suggests this feature was removed/never in jdk7.

Was this previously a Java feature that has since been removed, or was this never an official Java feature? And will this ever be added back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That document you link was a proposal, an investigation, an enhancement request.  This has never been adopted as an official feature of Java.

Comment: My understanding is that invokedynamic, which is what this document describes was adopted as an official feature though. Do you know why exotic identifiers where part of it/why it was removed?

Comment: The document that stated this would have said which version of java it supported. Which version was it?

Comment: InvokeDynamic went through the standard Java Spec Request process (JSR) and was approved for inclusion in the language, beginning with Java 8 (I believe).  This project https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/mlvm was never submitted as a JSR, it's just a project done by a few people at OpenJDK using Java open source.

Comment: The one thing that this and invokedynamic had in common was the intent to support non-Java languages with the JVM.  But this was never a part of the invokedynamic work.

Comment: Clearly the guys were a bit ambitious and opened bugs against Oracle, which was a waste of time.

Comment: @SeanF `invokedynamic` was added to the JVM in Java 7, see [Java Virtual Machine Support for Non-Java Languages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html), but is not used by the Java language until the introduction of lambda expressions in Java 8.